# What is the difference between Toyota GTS and TIS software?

Tags: toyota, obd-ii, obd

I've found two types of Toyota OEM software available.

One is the GTS ( Global Tech Stream ) software which is [freely available from Toyota's EU site](https://www.toyota-tech.eu/GTS/Wizard/Step5-Software.aspx).

The other is the Toyota TIS ( [Technical Information System](https://techinfo.toyota.com/techInfoPortal/appmanager/t3/ti;TISESSIONID=NzCkYpydvYQplkF5sMGJ1nT8jH2Br1JnTpSSJwcjQrv9dQHXht2l!-1442185568?_pageLabel=ti_vehicle_reprog&_nfpb=true) ) software which  seems to work with their dealer tools and is sold with various [third party tools on-line](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Best-Sale-MINI-VCI-V10-30-029-For-Toyota-Lexus-Scion-TIS-Techstream-OBD2-USB-Cable/32645949621.html?spm=2114.13010608.0.0.FOG7qO).